# Create a formula using row names in R

Tags: r, loops, sequence, formula

I am sorry about the title, I dont know how to describe my problem in a different way.

I have two dataframes:

```
set.seed(5)

Estimate_list = rnorm(7) 
Tvalue_list = rnorm(7) 

df1 = data.frame(Estimate = Estimate_list, Tvalue = Tvalue_list)
rownames(df1) <- c("Intercept", "ABC$V2", "ABC$V6", "ABC$V9", "ABC$V22", "ABC$V25", "ABC$V31")


set.seed(7)

df2 = data.frame(V1 = rnorm(3), V2 = rnorm(3),  V6 = rnorm(3), V8 = rnorm(3), V9 = rnorm(3),  V10 = rnorm(3),
             V14 = rnorm(3), V22 = rnorm(3), V25 = rnorm(3), V27 = rnorm(3), V31 = rnorm(3), V36 = rnorm(3))
```

I want to find an automatic way to do this:

```
Val_df1 = df1[1,1] + 
df1[2,1]*df2$V2  + df1[3,1]*df2$V6 + 
df1[4,1]*df2$V9  + df1[5,1]*df2$V22 +
df1[6,1]*df2$V25 + df1[7,1]*df2$V31
```

Basically I want use the first entry in df1 and then go down the first column in df1 and multiply the values with the columns in df2. But I only want to use the columns of df2, whose names are listed as part of the row names in df1.

Any ideas how to easily do tht automatically? Until now I typed everything manually, but its getting too much.

Comment: It sounds like a dot-product?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with a dot-product, sorry.

Comment: It implies `(1:5) %*% (6:10)` which is equal to `1 *  6 + 2 * 7 + 3 * 8 + 4 * 9 + 5 * 10`

Comment: No, that is not 100% what I want. I dont want every column in df2, just specific ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a crossprod

```
Val_df1New <- ((as.matrix(df2[, c("V2", "V6", "V9", "V22", "V25", "V31")]) %*%
        df1[-1, 1]) + df1[1, 1])[,1]

all.equal(Val_df1, Val_df1New)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Oh I see a problem now. I cant make the list with the names df2[, c("V2", "V6", "V9", "V22", "V25", "V31")] manually. That was my actual problem because I have really many of these to do. Do you know a way how to do it in a different way, that I dont have to create a list like that?

Comment: I found a way to solve the list issue! Thank you very much! Its working!